# What does AND operator do when operated between two objects in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

In OpenCV CamShift implementation there is a line ( just before the switch statement in onMouse() function in the code below ) of code which goes like this ,

```
selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);
```

where, selection is a Rect datatype of user defined dimensions ( selected by mouse callback ) and image is a frame from a video. The dimensions of selection and image do not match. What I don't understand is what is the purpose of this &= operator. I commented out this line of code and I couldn't figure out any difference. The code compilers just fine. I am not sure about what goes on inside when two objects are AND-ed. I could not find any resource that addresses this particular issue.

This is the original code:

```
#include "opencv2/video/tracking.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

Mat image;

bool backprojMode = false;
bool selectObject = false;
int trackObject = 0;
bool showHist = true;
Point origin;
Rect selection;
int vmin = 10, vmax = 256, smin = 30;

static void onMouse( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
{
    if( selectObject )
    {
        selection.x = MIN(x, origin.x);
        selection.y = MIN(y, origin.y);
        selection.width = std::abs(x - origin.x);
        selection.height = std::abs(y - origin.y);

        selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);
    }

    switch( event )
    {
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        origin = Point(x,y);
        selection = Rect(x,y,0,0);
        selectObject = true;
        break;
    case CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        selectObject = false;
        if( selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0 )
            trackObject = -1;
        break;
    }
}

static void help()
{
    cout << "\nThis is a demo that shows mean-shift based tracking\n"
            "You select a color objects such as your face and it tracks it.\n"
            "This reads from video camera (0 by default, or the camera number the user enters\n"
            "Usage: \n"
            "   ./camshiftdemo [camera number]\n";

    cout << "\n\nHot keys: \n"
            "\tESC - quit the program\n"
            "\tc - stop the tracking\n"
            "\tb - switch to/from backprojection view\n"
            "\th - show/hide object histogram\n"
            "\tp - pause video\n"
            "To initialize tracking, select the object with mouse\n";
}

const char* keys =
{
    "{1|  | 0 | camera number}"
};

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    help();

    VideoCapture cap;
    Rect trackWindow;
    int hsize = 16;
    float hranges[] = {0,180};
    const float* phranges = hranges;
    CommandLineParser parser(argc, argv, keys);
    int camNum = parser.get<int>("1");

    cap.open(argv[1]);

   /* if( !cap.isOpened() )
    {
        help();
        cout << "***Could not initialize capturing...***\n";
        cout << "Current parameter's value: \n";
        parser.printParams();
        return -1;
    }*/

    namedWindow( "Histogram", 0 );
    namedWindow( "CamShift Demo", 0 );
    namedWindow( "ROI", 0 );
    setMouseCallback( "CamShift Demo", onMouse, 0 );
    createTrackbar( "Vmin", "CamShift Demo", &vmin, 256, 0 );
    createTrackbar( "Vmax", "CamShift Demo", &vmax, 256, 0 );
    createTrackbar( "Smin", "CamShift Demo", &smin, 256, 0 );

    Mat frame, hsv, hue, mask, hist, histimg = Mat::zeros(200, 320, CV_8UC3), backproj;
    bool paused = false;

    for(;;)
    {
        if( !paused )
        {
            cap >> frame;
            if( frame.empty() )
                break;
        }

        frame.copyTo(image);

        if( !paused )
        {
            cvtColor(image, hsv, COLOR_BGR2HSV);

            if( trackObject )
            {
                int _vmin = vmin, _vmax = vmax;

                inRange(hsv, Scalar(0, smin, MIN(_vmin,_vmax)),
                        Scalar(180, 256, MAX(_vmin, _vmax)), mask);
                int ch[] = {0, 0};
                hue.create(hsv.size(), hsv.depth());
                mixChannels(&hsv, 1, &hue, 1, ch, 1);

                if( trackObject < 0 )
                {
                    Mat roi(hue, selection), maskroi(mask, selection);
                    calcHist(&roi, 1, 0, maskroi, hist, 1, &hsize, &phranges);
                    normalize(hist, hist, 0, 255, CV_MINMAX);

                    trackWindow = selection;
                    trackObject = 1;

                    histimg = Scalar::all(0);
                    int binW = histimg.cols / hsize;
                    Mat buf(1, hsize, CV_8UC3);
                    for( int i = 0; i < hsize; i++ )
                        buf.at<Vec3b>(i) = Vec3b(saturate_cast<uchar>(i*180./hsize), 255, 255);
                    cvtColor(buf, buf, CV_HSV2BGR);

                    for( int i = 0; i < hsize; i++ )
                    {
                        int val = saturate_cast<int>(hist.at<float>(i)*histimg.rows/255);
                        rectangle( histimg, Point(i*binW,histimg.rows),
                                   Point((i+1)*binW,histimg.rows - val),
                                   Scalar(buf.at<Vec3b>(i)), -1, 8 );
                    }
                imshow("ROI",roi);
                }

                calcBackProject(&hue, 1, 0, hist, backproj, &phranges);
                backproj &= mask;
                RotatedRect trackBox = CamShift(backproj, trackWindow,
                                    TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS | CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 10, 1 ));
                cout<<trackWindow.x<<"    "<<trackWindow.y<<endl;
                if( trackWindow.area() <= 1 )
                {
                    int cols = backproj.cols, rows = backproj.rows, r = (MIN(cols, rows) + 5)/6;
                    trackWindow = Rect(trackWindow.x - r, trackWindow.y - r,
                                       trackWindow.x + r, trackWindow.y + r) &
                                  Rect(0, 0, cols, rows);
                }

                if( backprojMode )
                    cvtColor( backproj, image, COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
                ellipse( image, trackBox, Scalar(0,0,255), 3, CV_AA );
            }
        }
        else if( trackObject < 0 )
            paused = false;

        if( selectObject && selection.width > 0 && selection.height > 0 )
        {
            Mat roi(image, selection);
            bitwise_not(roi, roi);
        }

        imshow( "CamShift Demo", image );
        //imshow( "Histogram", histimg );


        char c = (char)waitKey(50);
        if( c == 27 )
            break;
        switch(c)
        {
        case 'b':
            backprojMode = !backprojMode;
            break;
        case 'c':
            trackObject = 0;
            histimg = Scalar::all(0);
            break;
        case 'h':
            showHist = !showHist;
            if( !showHist )
                destroyWindow( "Histogram" );
            else
                namedWindow( "Histogram", 1 );
            break;
        case 'p':
            paused = !paused;
            break;
        default:
            int a=1;
            //continue;

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you check that `operator &=` was not redefined in some of the header files?

Comment: I did not find it trivial enough to look into the header files of a huge opensource library like OpenCV. But after reading your suggestion, I tried  to do that and there seems to be no re-definition.

Comment: Yeah I saw that.. but I could not figure out its functionality in this piece of code. I removed it and it worked just fine. That's exactly what I asked for instead of links. :)

Comment: @quamrana your URL is out of date and I received 404.

Comment: Updated link: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#Rect_ also mentions `&` and `&=`.

Comment: Updated link: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.3/d2/d44/classcv_1_1Rect__.html#details

Comment: @quamrana worth to delete outdated links, at least the top one which is expired (and pointing to Java documentation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The &-operator of two `Rect` objects results in a new `Rect` object, which is their intersection. Here they intersect the `selection` with the entire image-frame. I suspect that this is merely a precaution, done so that `selection` does not accidentally exceed the boundaries of the image.

Answer (score 2):

the & and | operators are overloaded for cv::Rect, `&` is the intersection, `|` the union of 2 Rects,

see for yourself:

```
Rect a(2,2,5,5);
Rect b(4,4,5,5);

Rect c = a & b;
Rect d = a | b;

cerr << a << endl << b << endl << c << endl << d << endl ;

[5 x 5 from (2, 2)]
[5 x 5 from (4, 4)]
[3 x 3 from (4, 4)] // intersection
[7 x 7 from (2, 2)] // union
```

---

in you code example above,

```
selection &= Rect(0, 0, image.cols, image.rows);
```

'selection' gets cropped to the valid image borders